# Number of Posts - Display number (x of x), if number is less than 4 ( 4 is the post_per_page)

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am showing 4 custom post type posts per category on a parent post type archive page with category rows. I want to show the count of the category posts `($list->found_posts)`, but I am limiting the displayed posts to a random 4 posts.

```
<?php $list = new WP_Query (array(
 'posts_per_page' => 4,
 'post_type' => 'business_listing',
 'category__in' => 5,
 'orderby' => 'rand'
 )) ;
```

I have successfully displayed the total number of posts for each category (business_listing is the post type)

```
$listCat = get_category('5');
$catName = get_field('display_name', $listCat);
$numberPosts = wp_count_posts($list);
echo '<h3 class="directory text-left">'. get_cat_name($category_id = '5') .' ('. $list->found_posts .' of '. $list->found_posts .') <a href="'. get_category_link($listCat) .'">View All</a></h3>';
```

[image]

The issue is, that some of my queries have less than the 4 posts_per_page. So I wanted to count UP TO 4, so if the value is less than 4 posts it will only count that number. For example if there are 2 posts, it will say 2 of 2. But if there are 30 posts, it would say 4 of 30.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the ternary operator:

```
echo '<h3 class="directory text-left">'. get_cat_name($category_id = '5') .' ('. ($list->found_posts < 4 ? $list->found_posts : 4)  .' of '. $list->found_posts .') <a href="'. get_category_link($listCat) .'">View All</a></h3>';
```

Comment: I tried that and it took out my query. I wonder what broke it. I found a solution - see below and let me know if Im doing it the right way

Comment: `if ($catName) {
  echo '<h3 class="directory text-left">'. $catName;
  if ($list->found_posts < 4){
  echo '('. $list->found_posts .' of '. $list->found_posts .'';
  } else {
  echo ' (4 of '. $list->found_posts .') <a href="'. get_category_link($listCat) .'">View All</a></h3>';
}
}`

Comment: Hey, can you please check if the edited one works. The one you have posted is essentially expanding the ternary operator into an if-else. Just that the ternary one is more readable. Maybe the additional brackets help